# empty queryset when overriding `BaseFilterView` and `ListView` ` django-filter==2.0.0.dev1`

Tags: django, django-filter

the problem is in how `BaseFilterView` changed:

**django-filter==1.0.2**

```
class BaseFilterView(FilterMixin, MultipleObjectMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filterset_class = self.get_filterset_class()
        self.filterset = self.get_filterset(filterset_class)
        self.object_list = self.filterset.qs
        context = self.get_context_data(filter=self.filterset,
                                        object_list=self.object_list)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**django-filter==2.0.0.dev1**

```
class BaseFilterView(FilterMixin, MultipleObjectMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filterset_class = self.get_filterset_class()
        self.filterset = self.get_filterset(filterset_class)

        if self.filterset.is_valid() or not self.get_strict():
            self.object_list = self.filterset.qs
        else:
            self.object_list = self.filterset.queryset.none()

        context = self.get_context_data(filter=self.filterset,
                                        object_list=self.object_list)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

in my `CustomLV(BaseFilterView, ListView)` I am facing problem of empty queryset when not specifying any filter. Providin an empty one like `?city=` or whatever makes it works.

I see [strict](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html?highlight=strict#strict) is about how filter should behave when smth goes with it wrong, but still not getting it right.

docs https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 1):

boom!

providing in `FilterSet` the `strict = False` fixed all problems.